# Using reflection in a Spy class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the following scenario.

```
public class A {

    //constructors

    @Value(${useMethodA:false})
    private boolean isUseMethodAEnabled;

    public void func() {
         if(isUseMethodAEnabled()) {
             a();
         } else {
             b();
         }
    }

}
//methods a() and b()
```

```
public class B {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    public void funcPrincipal() {
         A.a();
         System.out.println("Method A.a() was called");
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private B b;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private A a = new A();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "isUseMethodAEnabled", true);

        b.funcPrincipal();
        
        // if A is annotated with @Spy -> the "isUseMethodAEnabled" is always false
    }

}
```

See the above comment, please.

Is there any solution to change the "isUseMethodAEnabled" value from false to true using reflection?

If I switch to @Mock instead of @Spy everything works as expected. But for my test cases, I must use @Spy + @InjectMocks.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem, I print `a.isUseMethodAEnabled()` after calling `ReflectionTestUtils` and see "true".

Comment: @samabcde - I forgot to mention the "@InjectMocks" annotation that is used alongside "@Spy".

Comment: I see `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class mock.spy.A` this time, seems you have different mockito/springboot version.